# iphone 5 responsive fixed navbar glitch?

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, iphone-5

I am trying to finish my first website and thought it was pretty much finished but am having an issue with viewing some page layouts on an iPhone 5 (S and C). On my 4 it's fine and on an iPad I tested it on. Also fine on Android.

The issue is the fixed navbar (bootstrap) is bouncing around on the galley pages (it's a photography site) which have a horizontal scrolling div but it's ok on standard page layouts. I have disabled a mouse wheel plugin it's running to check if it's that and it has no effect on the iPhone 5 issue. Normal layout pages are fine.

the url is: http://www.pjrundle.co.uk

The problem occurs on any of the photography pages.

Sorry if this is a really obvious newbie question. Here is the css for the div containing the side scrolling gallery. I tried removing absolute positioning and no effect.

```
.scroll {
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 73px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `<header></header>` tags. It may be conflicting with `<nav class="navbar-fixed-top">`. It bounces on my iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.2

Comment: It doesn't bounce when tapping below the images, just on the images to scroll down. Therefore, I believe it to be a conflict between your scroller/carousel and touch input. You may have to add/remove the fixed property on touch events or remove keyboard support for scrolling, instead. I assume the same goes for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mijopabe, I fixed it in the end by adding:

```
.scroll {
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color: white;
 padding-top: 73px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 }
```

Not really sure why it worked without this on other browsers to be honest but fixed anyway.

Cheers.